# How to check if a numeric column value is in ascending or descending order. eg. 12345 or 654321

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help with a SQL query to check if a numeric column contains a number in ascending or descending order.

eg. 123456 or 654321

This is to avoid people entering some random values in a customer phone number column, users are required to give valid phone number input.

I want to achieve this without using a function.

UPDATE: @LukStorms had kindly answered my question. Many thanks. 
Thanks to others who looked at my question and left comments. However I would really appreciate if the comment helps solve the problem. My scenario is different, I cannot post the entire use case here. The ask is I must validate the column in the same way.

Comment: Server-side validation schemes that try to use regex patterns or other random logic to filter out bad input for email addresses and phone numbers almost always inconvenience valid customer(s). I recommend you look into schemes to send an SMS to the number with a validation code/URL and handle the response.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning for your reply. This validation can only be done in the database and I'm not allowed to use CLR functions either. So just looking for a TSQL script.

Comment: To what gain? If someone wants to give you a fake number and you tell them 123456 is not valid, they’ll just do 445566 or leave. Meanwhile if my number happens to be 403-812-3456 you’re going to alienate me, too. You can’t force someone to give you valid information; work on making the offering compelling enough (or require them) to give you real data. E-mail address and phone number can both be done using 2FA-style confirmations. Blocking sequences you think are impossible is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: If customers are putting in fake phone numbers you should take this as a sign that they do not want you to contact them by phone and do not think that this is required so make the field optional, Likely you will still end up with fake numbers but just harder to spot ones. I'd probably put your companies number if confronted with that when making a purchase. Generally you should be making customer experience as frictionless as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if it's like a sequence of digits?
Then you can simply use `LIKE`

> ```
> select num
> , cast(case 
>   when '1234567890123456789' like concat('%',num,'%')
>    then 1 
>   when '9876543210987654321' like concat('%',num,'%')
>    then 1 
>   else 0 end as bit) as isSequence
> from (values 
> (123456),
> (765432),
> (797204)
> ) nums(num)
> ```

| num | isSequence |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | True |
| 765432 | True |
| 797204 | False |

Or use `CHARINDEX`

> ```
> select num
> , cast(case 
>   when 0 < charindex(concat(num,''),'1234567890123456789') then 1 
>   when 0 < charindex(concat(num,''),'9876543210987654321') then 1 
>   else 0 end as bit) as isSequence
> from (values 
> (123456),
> (765432),
> (797204)
> ) nums(num)
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbc6babf9d016ca2027937dde888227f)*

Comment: Thanks a lot @LukStorms. It worked perfect. However just would like to know why you repeated the sequence twice. Is '01234567890' not enough?

Comment: For when it starts with a higher digit.  F.e. 890123. And then '012345678901234'  would be fine if you're sure it's only 6 digits.